# socket io get id of the disconnected socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, session-variables

I code a chat room using socket.io >1.0

In my chat room application I try to understand who is just disconnected. To do that I need to access socket's id. 
After the disconnect event is triggered,

```
      socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
          //need to learn socket's id here
      }
```

I cannot check who just left. I tried socket.id but that gave an error. I think the socket object is deleted because I cannot reach any part of it.

And I don't want to store all socket ids and loop through all of them when one is left. 
Then I tried saving the socket's id in session using session middleware, yet either they attach the data to socket object so using it is meaningless(all data is gone when disconnected) or they use the REST calls but I don't receive any REST call when someone(a socket) leaves the chatroom.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
          console.log("Connected Socket = " + socket.id)
          socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                 console.log("Disconnected Socket = " + socket.id);
          }
 }
```

Let me know if that works.

**EDIT1:** Essentially what you were doing was wrong, logically. The callback function associated to a connection was executed after somebody connected, and therefore lost, or, dereferenced within the event loop.

My answer will keep your callback referenced within the event loop, and if that connection is referenced again, you'd be able to identify what thread, or connection, called that method.

Comment: the first socket you mention, is it io? so it should be io.on('connection', function(socket){    .....   // do sth with socket }), I already do it that way, i.e., waiting for the disconnect event in the callback of connection, and that doesn't work

Comment: It should be yeah, small typo. 

Have you tried removing the "socket" parameter from your "disconnect" callback?

Comment: Regarding your edit, I can see that the disconnect event is fired, so it is not gone in the event loop. For example if i put console.log('someone disconnected'), in the callback of disconnect, it is fired. My problem is that I cannot access socket's id after the disconnect event occurs. I am certain that it is called.

Comment: You're correct, but the socket ID will definitely still be in scope, so long as you're not trying to overwrite it. Does your disconnect event look exactly the same as mine? I.e, nothing in the callback function parameters?

Comment: I tried disconnect without socket parameter, and it worked !  I didn't realise that I overwrite the socket by putting it into the parameters. Thanks a lot, I had been trying to figure it out for hours.